# Executing External Program in MS Access VBA and Catching Exception in VBA

Tags: shell, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2016

I want to execute a program from MS Access VBA Code. On click of a button, the program should execute.
I am using below code for this:

```
Dim myPath As String
myPath = "F:\MyExecutables\Prog_copy.exe"
iReturn = wsh.Run(myPath, windowStyle, waitOnReturn)
```

iReturn gives me 1 if the program executed successfully and 0 in case of any error or exception.
I want to get the exception details (at least the exception message) in VBA if the return value is 0.
How can do that.?

Note: I am using try catch blocks to handle different types of exceptions in my prg_Copy.exe.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your program outputs errors using `StdErr`, you can read errors using the following code:

```vb
Declare PtrSafe Sub SleepEx Lib "Kernel32.dll" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long, Optional ByVal bAlertable As Boolean = True)
Public Sub RunSomething()
    Dim wsh As Object
    Set wsh = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    Dim myPath As String
    myPath = "F:\MyExecutables\Prog_copy.exe"
    Dim ex As Object
    Set ex = wsh.Run("""" & myPath & """")
    Do While ex.Status = 0 'WshRunning
        SleepEx 50
    Loop
    If ex.Status = 2 'WshFailed
        Debug.Print ex.StdErr.ReadAll 'Print any errors
    End If
End Sub
```

Most console programs output errors to StdErr. If your program uses a different method of outputting errors, you need to use a different way to capture them.